# Breaking down very large Git repo into smaller repos and keeping history

Tags: git, github, version-control

I got this ridiculously large Git repo in GitHub. This repo consists of several independent projects that I want to break down into their own separate repos, and continue their development there.

```
ridiculously-large.git
├───Project1
├───Project2
├───...
└───Project1000
```

For now, I'm interested in `Project2`. I want to "clone" `Project2` only, along with its history, to a new repo `Project2.git` exclusively dedicated to it, and leave `ridiculously-large.git` only for historical purposes.

So far, I've been somewhat successful with the following approach:

1. First, create a brand new repo in GitHub, `Project2` with no commit history (this seems to be important in order to avoid those *"fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories..."*) and clone it.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/me/Project2.git
   ```

   Thus, my local repo is already configured with default remote `origin` pointing to the new GitHub repo that will be specific to further development of `Project2`.
2. Then, within the new local repo:

   ```
   git config core.sparseCheckout true
   echo Project2/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
   ```
3. Then, I add a temporary **upstream** remote `temp` pointing to `ridiculously-large.git`:

   ```
   git remote add -f temp https://github.com/me/ridiculously-large.git
   ```

   So far so good. There is still nothing to commit.
4. Then, pull the `master` branch from the `temp` remote into a new `work` local branch:

   ```
   git pull temp master:work
   ```

   (I do this because of personal practice: I never work in any local `master` branch, whether or not the there is an upstream branch configured for it.)
5. This successfully accomplishes the goal of pulling only the sources related to `Project2` into the working copy. So far so good.
6. Now, after I push `work` to the newly dedicated remote `origin`:

   ```
   git checkout work
   git push --set-upstream origin work
   ```

   ... I see **THE WHOLE SHEBANG** pushed to the newly dedicated remote for `Project2`, miserably defeating the entire purpose of this endeavor.

## The Question(s)

- What is the established/recommended approach to achieve my goal?
- Is it possible to do it as a variation of what I'm doing (or not doing correctly?)
- Are there any other Git constructs more appropriate altogether?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: Interesting... I will review. Thanks!